# Eclipse and Nashorn throwing java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, nashorn, scada

I am using the Eclipse SCADA framework which uses Nashorn to integrate JavaScript into Java.

One feature of Nashorn is that you are able to call Java code directly from the JavaScript fragments.

I have read on some tutorials that in order to invoke a java method you have to use:

```
var MyJavaClass = Java.type('countdown2.test2');
```

but I get the following **errors**:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.scada.vi.ui.draw2d 4 0 2018-05-09 15:45:08.572
!MESSAGE countdown2.test2 cannot be found by org.eclipse.scada.vi.ui.draw2d_0.3.0.v20160226-1536
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: countdown2.test2 cannot be found by org.eclipse.scada.vi.ui.draw2d_0.3.0.v20160226-1536
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:397)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:421)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.access$300(NashornScriptEngine.java:73)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.scada.utils.script.ScriptExecutor.executeScript(ScriptExecutor.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.scada.utils.script.ScriptExecutor.access$1(ScriptExecutor.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.scada.utils.script.ScriptExecutor$3.call(ScriptExecutor.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.scada.utils.script.Scripts.executeWithClassLoader(Scripts.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.scada.utils.script.ScriptExecutor.execute(ScriptExecutor.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.scada.utils.script.ScriptExecutor.execute(ScriptExecutor.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.scada.vi.ui.draw2d.SymbolController.runUpdate(SymbolController.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.scada.vi.ui.draw2d.SymbolController.handleDataUpdate(SymbolController.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.scada.vi.ui.draw2d.SymbolController$2.run(SymbolController.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at ejemplo.Application.start(Application.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: countdown2.test2 cannot be found by org.eclipse.scada.vi.ui.draw2d_0.3.0.v20160226-1536
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.findClass(Context.java:1051)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.simpleType(NativeJava.java:498)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.type(NativeJava.java:322)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.type(NativeJava.java:314)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.type(NativeJava.java:310)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$23$1510$cilindrovertical.updateValve(cilindrovertical.js:46)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$2$onUpdate.:program(onUpdate:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    ... 38 more
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am writing the JavaScript code in the `"cilindrovertical.js"` file and I am referencing the `"test2"` class which is in the `"src"` file. How should I write the Java.type code?

Eclipse Project Explorer

[image]

Thanks in advance for answers.